# Trying to use Strategic Design Interface, but cannot get data into variable

Tags: java, interface

I'm a student just learning about interfaces. 
I have an abstract class using an Interface, which is called from an extended class. The problem is, when I try to set the "power" variable it returns "Nuclear@3339ed6d" instead of "test". You will find this in the Extended class at the bottom. All code compiles and runs. I would appreciate any help.

**//INTERFACE:**

```
public interface MoveType  
{
   public void move();  
}
```

**//IMPLEMENTATION:**

```
public class Nuclear implements MoveType
{   
   public String move()
   {
      return ("test");   
   }
}
```

**//ABSTRACT CLASS**

```
public abstract class Ship 
{
   private String name;
   private String year;
   private MoveType power;

   // Constructors
   public Ship(){}

   public Ship(String n, String y)
   {
      name = n;
      year = y;
   }

   // Getters
   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }
   public String getYear()
   {
      return year;
   }
   public MoveType getPower()
   {
      return power;
   }
   // Setters
   public void setName(String n)
   {
      name = n;
   }
   public void setYear(String y)
   {
      year = y;
   }
   public void setPower(MoveType p)
   {
      power = p;
   }
}
```

**//EXTENDED CLASS**

```
public class CargoShip extends Ship
{
   private int tonnage;  //cargo capacity in tonnage

   // Constructors
   public CargoShip(){}

   public CargoShip(String n, String y, int t)
   {
      super(n,y);
      tonnage = t;
      setPower(new Nuclear());
   }

   // Getter
   public int getTonnage()
   {
      return tonnage;
   }
   // Setter
   public void setTonnage(int t)
   {
      tonnage = t;
   }
   // To String Override
   public String toString()
   {
      String str = "Name: " + super.getName() + "\n Cargo Capacity in Tonnage: " + tonnage + "\n Ship is powered by: " + super.getPower();

      return str;
   }
```

Comment: Its default `toString()` method that return `Nuclear@3339ed6d`. You haven't called `move` method anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to override the `toString` method in `Nuclear` or invoke `super.getPower().move()` to return the expected string.

Comment: THANKS!! I added .move() to the end of the toString method and it worked! Thanks Bhesh. And thanks everyone for responding. Your help is very appreciated.  -Joseph